# `include`able ActiveRecord association with additional where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 `ActiveRecord` models:

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fields
  has_many :forms
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doc
end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doc
end
```

Each of these models has a `version` column. On `Doc` it's the most recent version, and on `Form` and `Field` it is the version of the doc when they were created. It's easy enough to query for the fields for a given form:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doc
  has_many :fields, ->(form) { where(version: form.version) }, through: :doc
end
```

Is there any way for me to construct the relationship between `Form` and `Field` such that I can eager load the fields on forms? i.e. I want to be able to say:

```
doc.forms.includes(:fields)
```

I'm using Postgres as my data store.

Comment: What is it that does not work in the code you have provided here?

Comment: `doc.forms.includes(:fields)` will raise a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'version' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is this data structure set in stone? Why don´t fields belong to a form directly. Then they would not need to know their own version and this query would be super easy? Otherwise it can be solved but I think we need to write some custom SQL...

Comment: The problem is that multiple forms might have the same set of fields. Every time the doc is updated, it creates a set of fields with the new version. When a form is created it uses the latest version of the fields when it was filled out, but we want it to keep that set of fields, even if the doc is updated.

Comment: Why do this with versions on the form? If you add a many to many relationship between the form and fields you loose a little bit of database integrity but things will be much simpler.

Comment: Yeah, we may go that route, though it would require a bulk insert in the join table every time we create a new form. The thing with it as-is is that it's also easy to backport a field as necessary to older versions. Just make a copy and assign the old version.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the conversation above I think it might be hard to solve with a  clean activerecord query. And I think that this fact might be a little bit of a smell and might tell you that the way your database is structured might not be optimal.

Given this it can be solved by writing a custom join

```
has_many :version_fields, -> { joins('INNER JOIN "forms" tmp on "tmp"."version" = "fields"."version"') }, through: :doc, source: :fields
```

In this code we let the combination of the original join which enforces the id constraint and this custom sql which enforces the version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I spent a while banging my head on it, but this isn't one of the things I came up with.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! I ran into a PG syntax error with the backticks, so had to replace them with double quotes in my query.

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to have to take that back. If you have multiple forms with different versions, each form gets all of the fields for every version. e.g. one form with version 5 and another with version 10, if they both have the same doc, it will return fields with version 5 or 10 for either of the forms.